# Port 80 in use, but it's not? (Docker Compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using an M1 MacBook

Docker error when starting a container:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

But if I run `sudo lsof -i :80`, nothing is returned for that port

Comment: There are more reasons than "in use" that something can be unavailable

Comment: ...in particular, ports below 1024 are only available for root to bind. (Historically, one has typically used superservers for this, having something like xinetd bind to those ports and pass the socket along to whatever less-privileged program is supposed to answer requests on it).